# Use of :let modifier in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I wonder what is the sense of a `:let` modifier when using the `for` loop in Clojure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:let` lets you define named values, in the same sense that the let special form lets you do it:

```
(for [i (range 10) 
      :let [x (* i 2)]] 
  x) ;;=> (0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(for [i (range 10)] 
  (let [x (* i 2)] 
  x)) ;;=> (0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18)
```

except when used in combination with `:when` (or `:while`):

```
(for [i (range 10) 
          :let [x (* i 2)]
          :when (> i 5)] 
      x) ;;=> (12 14 16 18)

(for [i (range 10)] 
  (let [x (* i 2)] 
    (when (> i 5) x))) ;;=> (nil nil nil nil nil nil 12 14 16 18)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:let` to create bindings inside a list comprehension like `let`.

To quote an example of the [clojure documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for):

```
user=> (for [x [0 1 2 3 4 5]
             :let [y (* x 3)]
             :when (even? y)]
         y)
(0 6 12)
```

The trick is that you can now use `y` in the `:while` and `:when` modifiers, instead of writing something like

```
user=> (for [x [0 1 2 3 4 5]
             :when (even? (* x 3))]
         (* x 3))
```